# How to handle events in dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a dynamic questionnaire, loading the next question dynamically, but when I load the second question, the event of the button <kbd>next2</kbd> doesn't respond as if there were no event.

I think it's because I load the input with a JavaScript function. What do I have to do to make it work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var question2 = `
            <form>
               <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="age">
        <input type="submit" id="next2">
            </form>
          `;
  var question3 = `
            <form>
              <input type = "email" id="email" placeholder="email">
               <input type="submit" id="next3">
              </form>
              `;

  $('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(1);
    $(".questions").html(question2);
  });
  $("#next2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".questions").html(question3);
  });
  $("#next3").click(function() {
    alert('Cool');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="questions">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <button type="submit" value="Next" id="next">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using `.click()`, you can try assigning `onclick=nextClicked()` then calling the `nextClicked()' function which assigns the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one event handler for all this, not multiple.

You are inserting the HTML into the element with the class  `questions` with `$(".questions").html`.  Given that you should hook the event handlers to that element with the `questions` class to be as close to the element as possible (not make it traverse the entire DOM looking for things in the events.

Here I took the CURRENT html and saved it to `myApp` which I created to hold stuff and not pollute the global namespace; Then I cycle back to it on the last.  Odd that you have both `button` and `input` type submit but I also handle that.  Since these are submit buttons in a form, I added the `submit` event in case that is how it gets triggered.

```js
$(function() {
  let myApp = {};

  myApp.question2 = ` <form>I am 2
    <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="age">
    <input type="submit" id="next2"  data-nextthing="question3">
  </form>
`;
  myApp.question3 = ` <form>I am 3
   <input type = "email" id="email" placeholder="email">
   <input type="submit" id="next3"  data-nextthing="question1">
 </form>
 `;

  myApp.question1 = $(".questions").html(); // just to store it
  $(".questions")
    .on('click submit', 'form, button[type="submit"], input[type="submit"]', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      let d = $(this).data('nextthing');
      $(event.delegateTarget).html(myApp[d]);
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <button type="submit" value="Next" id="next" data-nextthing="question2">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(document)`. It is a function trigger for any click event in the document. Then inside you can use the jquery `on("click","#idname",somefunction)`, where the second argument specifies which specific element to target. In this case every element inside the body.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#next', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".questions").html(question2);
  });
```